# CakePHP 3: Caching database object in component

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.1

i'm trying to save an database object from the (plugin) **component** into the CakePHP Cache.

This works ( note the toArray() )

```
        $domains = Cache::read('domains', 'long');

        if ($domains === false) {

            $domainsTable = TableRegistry::get('DomainManager.Domains');
            $domains = $domainsTable->find('all', ['fields' => ['id', 'name']]);
            $domains = $domains->toArray();

            Cache::write('domains', $domains, 'long');
            return $domains;
        }
```

But this fails:

```
        $domains = Cache::read('domains', 'long');

        if ($domains === false) {

        $domainsTable = TableRegistry::get('DomainManager.Domains');
        $domains = $domainsTable->find('all', ['fields' => ['id', 'name']]);

        Cache::write('domains', $domains, 'long');
        return $domains;
    }
```

The error given from CakePHP is
**Error: You cannot serialize or unserialize PDO instances**

Sorry if i'm just doing something wrong, i just switched from Cake2 to Cake3 and could nothing find in the Documentation.

Thanks for any glues!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `find` function does not return results, it returns a query object that you can use to fetch results. Calling `toArray` on this will retrieve all the entities and give you something you can cache. (It can be confusing, as `toArray` is also used to convert entities into arrays in other situations.)

Comment: Hi Greg, thanks for your answer. 
But doesn't the CakePHP Documentation (http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/caching.html#writing-to-a-cache) say 
"Cache::write() can store any type of object and is ideal for storing results of model finds" 
or does this mean only arrays can be stored in the cache? 

It could be that i'm just misreading the documentation on this.

Comment: "Results" typically means the rows returned by the database. `find` does not return rows, it returns a query object that can be used to retrieve the rows, in various ways. You can store lots of things in the cache, but query objects are not one of them.

Comment: Okay, thanks! :-) Looks like i should take a deep look into the new ORM once more.

Comment: I found something in the documentation (http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/retrieving-data-and-resultsets.html#using-finders-to-load-data), `$query->toArray()` executes the query, as does `$query->all()`. Thanks Greg for the hint!